# Swift convert Any to String and assign to UIlabel (Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Tags: ios, swift

I have this Dictionary

var detailItem: Dictionary?

I am trying to get the Any and convert it to a String and then assign to UILabel like so:

```
self.firstName.text = detail!["firstname"] as? String
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Which I dont understand because first name is not nil, its James (not "James") but just James, if I print it I can see it:

```
print(detail!["firstname"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

How to do I assign Any to UiLabel text?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `self.firstName` is nil. Is `firstName` an outlet? Are you sure it is connected?

Comment: Agree. Try self.firstName.text = "HI" first

Comment: @rmaddy This is clearly the issue here. You should post this as an answer :)

Comment: I tried self.firstName.text = "HI"  and yes I get the same error

Comment: firstName is an outlet and yes it is connected

Comment: No, it's not connected. If it was connected you wouldn't get the error (assuming the error really happens on the `self.firstName.text = "Hi"` line).

Comment: What part of the view controller code (which function) are you assigning the value to the outlet in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to unwrap the optional string value from your dictionary.

```
if let firstName = detail?["firstname"] as? String {
    self.firstName?.text = firstName
}
```

This ensures your label's text will only get set when there is a value for "firstname" in your Dictionary.

If that still crashes then your label might be nil. If your using an outlet it might not be set.

Comment: It crashes, yes I am using an outlet

Comment: Your outlet must be broken then. Try the updated answer. It shouldn't crash, but since the outlet isn't working you would see the text in the label.